# Repo commits not showing up on profile

Tags: git, github, commit

As the title says my git commits aren't showing on my profile for a specific repo. I am pushing the commit so it's not that. I've pushed about 40 commits in the past few days and nothing has appeared. Other people in this repo are committing and it's showing up for them.

I assumed it was an issue with my local git profile but today when I committed to another repo it worked fine. Does anyone have any ideas on what it could be? Its also not showing me as a contributor of the repo but I've been contributing the most and I'm an admin of it

Answer (score 2):

The email associated with the commit author is the main element considered by GitHub when showing contribution on a user's profile.

So in the specific repository, check what `git config user.email` (and `user.name`) returns, and compare it to a repository where your commits are shown in your profile.

---

Double-check also the official documentation "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)".

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your account on GitHub.com.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch
>   - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with project sites)

So even if the `user.name`/`email` are correct, commits pushed in a non-default branch would not show up in your contributions.